# Bad rendering of parentheses of binomial coefficient in Beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I am working with documentclass Beamer version 3.10 and I have a problem with the rendering of the parentheses of the binomial coefficient. Here the code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 8pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif} %required for article-like displaying of math

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,t]

$\dbinom{n}{k}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

The weird thing is that if I change the documentclass to `article` and comment the line `\usefonttheme{serif}`, then I get

[image]

which is the desired rendering. Any idea of how to correct the printing of the binomial coefficient in beamer? Why this strange behavior in Beamer?

Note: I have tried with `\choose`, with `$\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}$` and putting the expression within an `equation` environment, but without success.

Comment: Thanks to @StevenBSegletes and Svend Tveskaeg by their replies, all of their solutions work, I just add an additional question in my original post about why that behavior in Beamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 8pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif} %required for article-like displaying of math
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain,t]

$\dbinom{n}{k}$  DBINOM

$\scaleleftright[1.7ex]{(}{\Centerstack{n\\k}}{)}$  SCALEREL + STACKENGINE

$\parenVectorstack{n\\k}$ JUST STACKENGINE

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use 8pt font size, 10pt does the trick:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$\dbinom{n}{k}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: With global font size of 8 pt and sorrounding the math expression with `\large` also works: `{\large [\binom{n}{k}]}` In any case I still do not understand why is all this necessary in Beamer.